# How to add parameters to event functions in TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

While trying to implement the atomic design of react, I encountered a problem with the event function. I want to pass the setState function in the parent component to the onChange function in the child component.

```js
// InputItem(parent component)
import { useState } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import Input from '../../../components/atom/Input';

const InputStyle = styled.input`
  font-size: 15px;
`;

function InputItem() {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const onChange = (
    e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>,
    setState: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<string>>
  ) => {
    setState(e.target.value);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <Input
        InputStyle={InputStyle}
        type="text"
        value={email}
        onChange={(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) =>
          onChange(e, setEmail)
        }
        placeholder={'ID'}
      />
    </>
  );
}
export default InputItem;
```

```
// Input(children component)
import { StyledComponent } from 'styled-components';

interface InputProps {
  InputStyle: StyledComponent<'input', any, {}, never>;
  type: string;
  value: string;
  onChange: (
    e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>,
    setState: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<string>>
  ) => void;
  placeholder: string;
}

function Input({ InputStyle, type, value, onChange, placeholder }: InputProps) {
  return (
    <InputStyle
      type={type}
      value={value}
      onChange={onChange} // An error occurred in this part
      placeholder={placeholder}
    ></InputStyle>
  );
}

export default Input;
```

But in onChange of Input component, I get the following error

```
'(props: StyledComponentPropsWithAs<"input", any, {}, never, "input", "input">): ReactElement<StyledComponentPropsWithAs<"input", any, {}, never, "input", "input"> , string | JSXElementConstructor<...>>') gave the following error:
   Type '(e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>, setState: Dispatch<SetStateAction<string>>) => void' cannot be assigned to type 'ChangeEventHandler<HTMLInputElement>'.
```

How can I pass an event function to a subcomponent?

Comment: Your `InputProps` type is wrong. There shouldn't be a second parameter for `onChange`.

Comment: onChange={(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void => onChange(e, setEmail)}